# One SQL, lots of SharePoint 2010 Servers, and lots of Databases to clean

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, uninstall, cleanup, remove

I have a dedicated server running SQL server and many web servers running SharePoint 2010 installations. All the SharePoint web servers are using the same SQL server for storing/creating databases.

As I know, When SharePoint is installed it creates a collection of databases for itself to work (around 8 or 10).

Two Questions:

- How can I know which group of databases belong to which installation of SharePoint?
- When I uninstall SharePoint, the databases remain on the SQL server, how do I clean SQL from a removed/uninstalled SharePoint installation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it, using the PowerShell:

- Go to Start => All Programs => Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products => SharePoint 2010 Management Shell.
- Type the Command: Get-SPDatabase

The list of DBs for the SharePoint installation will be shown to you.

Comment: As to your second question just delete the databases